# What is the return type of JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options:) in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsjsonserialization

I made the json parser in swift language.
But, many of people are using like below.

```
let jsonParsed = JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
guard let jsonDict = jsonParsed as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> else { return }
...
```

Then, I wonder the type of *jsonParsed*. The JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:options:) function reference describes that the result type is just *Any*.
I know the type is Dictionary because JSON. The KEY is String type but, VALUE is *AnyObject*? How about *Any*?
I know the difference between *AnyObject* and *Any*. *Any* also includes value type, function type.
Number is also value type in swift: Int, Float, Double...
Is that impossible return type is value type?

Comment: you should cast to `[String: Any]`if your top-level  json object is a dictionary. if you have an array of dictionaries just cast to `[[String: Any]]`

Comment: It may be better to use Codable/Decodable then you end up with proper structs of known types. Much cleaner and type safe.

Answer (score 0):

Json can be array also. This is valid josn

```
[
  "1",
  "2",
  "3"
  ]
```

You can use this site to verify [https://jsoneditoronline.org/][1].
When you give fragmentsallowed option in the function json result can be Int,Float or any other primitive data type.

So it is not possible to return type in compile time. At run time it is possible. But return type is decided at run time.